# ubuntu 17.04 slow bootup

Tags: boot, 17.04

I have a really slow bootup, I will post my boot.log, can someone figure out something?

[boot.log](https://pastebin.com/tFbDSgBj)

### Contents of `systemd-analyze blame`

```
     20.874s dev-sda7.device
     18.101s keyboard-setup.service
     17.900s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
     15.091s nmbd.service
      7.179s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.931s click-system-hooks.service
      6.627s ModemManager.service
      4.703s accounts-daemon.service
      4.338s smbd.service
      4.120s grub-common.service
      3.919s NetworkManager.service
      3.760s repowerd.service
      3.758s postfix@-.service
      3.669s systemd-sysctl.service
      2.344s fwupd.service
      1.863s upower.service
      1.808s colord.service
      1.700s avahi-daemon.service
      1.684s lightdm.service
      1.683s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      1.591s wpa_supplicant.service
      1.126s udisks2.service
      1.008s run-rpc_pipefs.mount
       963ms rsyslog.service
       945ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6E38\x2dB283.service
       944ms polkit.service
       834ms apport.service
       748ms user@1000.service
       681ms dev-mqueue.mount
       680ms dev-hugepages.mount
       679ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       645ms apparmor.service
       575ms lm-sensors.service
       552ms tlp.service
       512ms rtirq.service
       507ms thermald.service
       475ms vboxdrv.service
       454ms irqbalance.service
       446ms nvidia-persistenced.service
       367ms systemd-journald.service
       311ms binfmt-support.service
       303ms dns-clean.service
       280ms systemd-resolved.service
       225ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       224ms ufw.service
       208ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       187ms networking.service
       165ms systemd-logind.service
       160ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       152ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       126ms plymouth-read-write.service
       126ms packagekit.service
       110ms setvtrgb.service
       101ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
        92ms dev-sda8.swap
        71ms boot-efi.mount
        49ms systemd-udevd.service
        47ms rpcbind.service
        43ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        24ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        22ms bluetooth.service
        21ms speech-dispatcher.service
        20ms rtkit-daemon.service
        18ms switcheroo-control.service
        15ms pppd-dns.service
        15ms systemd-journal-flush.service
        14ms alsa-restore.service
        12ms plymouth-start.service
        12ms glances.service
        11ms nscd.service
         7ms snapd.autoimport.service
         5ms hddtemp.service
         3ms resolvconf.service
         3ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
         3ms ureadahead-stop.service
         2ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
         2ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         2ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1.service
         2ms nfs-config.service
         2ms vboxballoonctrl-service.service
         2ms vboxautostart-service.service
         2ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
         2ms vboxweb-service.service
         2ms systemd-random-seed.service
         2ms systemd-backlight@leds:asus::kbd_backlight.service
         1ms systemd-modules-load.service
         1ms console-setup.service
         1ms systemd-user-sessions.service
         1ms openvpn.service
         1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
       492us snapd.socket
```

### Contents of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

```
graphical.target @1min 59.841s
└─multi-user.target @1min 59.841s
└─nmbd.service @1min 44.749s +15.091s
└─network-online.target @1min 44.748s
└─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 37.568s +7.179s
└─NetworkManager.service @1min 33.648s +3.919s
└─dbus.service @1min 33.517s
└─basic.target @1min 33.515s
└─sockets.target @1min 33.515s
└─snapd.socket @1min 33.514s +492us
└─sysinit.target @1min 33.437s
└─apparmor.service @25.098s +645ms
└─local-fs.target @25.097s
└─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @1min 55.993s
└─run-user-1000.mount @1min 52.689s
└─local-fs-pre.target @21.417s
└─systemd-remount-fs.service @21.391s +24ms
└─system.slice @3.222s
└─-.slice @2.636s
```

Comment: Can you please show the output of `systemd-analyze blame` and a `systemd-analyze`?  Could be anything but that would be a reasonable way to begin to identify slow loading processes and kernel vs userspace boot split times.

Comment: [systemd-analyze blame] (https://pastebin.com/4GZVRNZd) [systemd-analyze] 'Startup finished in 6.560s (firmware) + 5.640s (loader) + 5.257s (kernel) + 3min 3.687s (userspace) = 3min 21.145s'

Comment: Please paste the outcome of the command from 'The Pizza Overload`

Comment: When did this start? Have you upgraded all software/kernel to latest versions? Is shutdown slow as well?

Comment: Comparing to my own `systemd-analayze blame` the first four lines in yours should not be there, which would save about 75 seconds.

Comment: Show me the `terminal` output of `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `free -h` and `swapon -s` and I'll take a look. Start new comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.